# Web Service unavailable after restart Glassfish

Tags: web-services, jakarta-ee, glassfish-3, soap-client

now I have this new problem. I´m using Glassfish 3.1.2.2 to host an application that has a Web Service to communicate with another application outside the server, mainly a swing desktop application. Every thing works fine, but (always a but), if we need to restart the glassfish for some reason, the destop application didn't find the ws, so we need to redeploy the application in the Glassfish and every thing works fine again.

At the begining we thought that was a problem in the desktop client, so we refresh the connection to the web service, nothing. After that, we tested the web service from the netbeans option to do that and we get this warning:

[image]

The solution that we found was to redeploy the application, as you guest, when the application will be in production this is not a aceptable solution.

My application is build with jdk 7.0.21, using Netbeans 7.3, JSF 2.0, PrimeFaces 3.5, JPA 2.0, the web service was constructed following this [tutorial](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/flower_overview.html).

This is the message received in the log of the desktop test application:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.ClientTransportException: The server sent HTTP status code 404: Not Found
>       at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.checkStatusCode(HttpTransportPipe.java:296)
>       at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.createResponsePacket(HttpTransportPipe.java:245)
>       at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.process(HttpTransportPipe.java:203)
>       at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.processRequest(HttpTransportPipe.java:122)
>       at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.DeferredTransportPipe.processRequest(DeferredTransportPipe.java:95)
>       at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:626)
>       at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:585)
>       at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:570)
>       at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:467)
>       at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.Stub.process(Stub.java:308)
>       at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.doProcess(SEIStub.java:146)
>       at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:98)
>       at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:78)
>       at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:129)
>       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy30.hello(Unknown Source)
>       at com.spontecorp.testws.TestWSFrame.invokeWSButtonActionPerformed(TestWSFrame.java:137)
>       at com.spontecorp.testws.TestWSFrame.access$100(TestWSFrame.java:14)
>       at com.spontecorp.testws.TestWSFrame$2.actionPerformed(TestWSFrame.java:62)
>       at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
>       at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
>       at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
>       at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
>       at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
>       at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
>       at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
>       at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
>       at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
>       at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
>       at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
>       at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:729)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:688)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:686)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:702)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:700)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:699)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)

My question is:
- Do I need to setup something in Glassfish after deployment an application that serves a web service?, if so, where?

Answer (score 0):

Had  the same problem after refractoring, had to create a new webservice at server (and then just copy the old code), after that I re-imported the new WSDL and made the right changes to the code (to the new name of the webservice).

Problem was, for me at least, that after refractoring I couldn't call

```
com.package.class.MyWebService_Service service;
```

Dont know why, and there is probably a better solution for this instead of "recreating".

Comment: I'll try this solution too. If i get a solution I ´ll let you know here

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this helps you in your case, but at least the [tutorial](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/flower_overview.html) didn't work for me either out-of-the-box. The error I got was the same: "`com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.ClientTransportException: The server sent HTTP status code 404: Not Found`".

I managed to get the web service client working by re-creating the reference to the web service. The problem was that it referred to `http://localhost:8080/FlowerAlbumService/FlowerService?wsdl` but the service was running on `http://localhost:8080/FlowerServiceService/FlowerService?wsdl` (you can see this by [testing the web service](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/flower-code-ws.html#test-ws)).

So I deleted the web service in the Client's Web Service References node, created a new web service client, and specified `http://localhost:8080/FlowerServiceService/FlowerService?wsdl` as the WSDL URL. Perhaps this helps to solve your problem, too.

Comment: Ok, I´ll try your solution. If I can solve the problem I´ll post it here.

Comment: I did check and there´s a different situation. My problem just happen after restart the glassfish server.